# Trigger time at specific time requires multithreading?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I'd like to know if I schedule a timer to run at a specific time (say 2 minutes from now), my program will still run other features, or if for that I require multithreading?

I'm having troubles with this. I configured a timer to run 2 minutes from now (basically to send a message to the console), yet I still have to deal with the UI.

My code is:

```
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
        String year = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy"));
        String yearMonth = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM"));
        String day = "14";
        Date date = dateFormatter.parse(yearMonth + "-" + day + " 05:08");
        long milis = date.getTime();
        long milisNow = (new Date()).getTime();
        long milisDif = milis - milisNow;

        MyTimeTask task = new MyTimeTask("cenas");
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(task, milisDif);
        Thread.sleep(milisDif+1l);
        timer.cancel();
```

Now the class that extends TimerTask:

```
public class MyTimeTask extends TimerTask {
    private String name;

    public MyTimeTask(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! The equivalent of `Date` is `Instant` in `java.time`. You don't need `Date` workarounds here.

Comment: but will that solve my problem?

Comment: No, it's just a little hint for you, so you don't mix up time APIs for no reason.